# Additional condition to function - Odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I have this method:

```
@api.multi
@api.constrains('order_lines', 'order_lines.qty', 'order_lines.isbn')
def check_quantity(self):
    for rec in self:
        if rec.order_lines:
            for line in rec.order_lines:
                if line.qty > line.isbn.qty_available:
                    raise Warning(('Quantity is invalid.'))
                if not line.isbn:
                    raise Warning(('Enter​ ​at least​ ​1​ ​ISBN to produce'))
                else:
                    self.write({'state': 'inprogress',},)
```

It functions perfectly for the `qty_available` conditional, and the `inprogress` state, but if I don't add any `isbn` which is a `Many2one` for `product.product` it doesn't throw any error, but doesn't works either.

It should raise the `'Enter​ ​at least​ ​1​ ​ISBN to produce'` Warning, but it just loads and that's it.

If You need further explanation, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use `self` inside the loop always remember that because if you call
a method it will be applied on all the records inside it.

and don't call write inside `@api.constrains` or `depends` this will cause recursive error. because this two decorator are called in `create` or `write` method.

```py
@api.multi
@api.constrains('order_lines', 'order_lines.qty', 'order_lines.isbn')
def check_quantity(self):
    for rec in self:
        if rec.order_lines:
            for line in rec.order_lines:
                if not line.isbn:
                    # and check for the product before the quantity
                    # because if there is no product line.isbn.qty_available 
                    # will raise exception
                    raise Warning(('Enter​ ​at least​ ​1​ ​ISBN to produce'))

                if line.qty > line.isbn.qty_available:
                    raise Warning(('Quantity is invalid.'))

                else:
                    # if you use self here you will update all records
                    # and don't use write in the constrains
                    # try to use update it may work if not you need to override write or create method
                    rec.update({'state': 'inprogress',},)
                # or if you are changing just one field
                # rec.state = 'inprogress'
```

Comment: One thing api.constrains is called when you save the changes it checks your data in every call to create or write method no need to call it using a button. And if you want to check the quantity in real time use onchange event and return a warning but not the order model define the function in the line model

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I make some modification, i use ValidationError instead Warning, and dont use `@api.multi`, the system will use `@api.one` when we use `constraint`, and there is a note in last line

```
from openerp.exceptions import ValidationError

#@api.constrains('order_lines', 'order_lines.qty', 'order_lines.isbn')
@api.one
def check_quantity(self):
    for line in self.order_lines:
        if line.isbn.qty_available and (line.qty > line.isbn.qty_available):
            raise ValidationError("Quantity is invalid. %s" % line.qty)
        if not line.isbn:
            raise ValidationError('Enter​ ​at least​ ​1​ ​ISBN to produce')
        else:
            self.write({'state': 'inprogress',},) # here you have used @api.multi, and this not correct
```

Comment: Hi, Thank You, but this is a button, I need api.multi, I'm going to try with multi anyways and write You back

Comment: Same thing with ValidationError, I have to use api.multi, otherwise I'll take the 1 argument, 5 given, error, any ideas?

Comment: @NeoVe if you are adding constraints on button then in my opinion you are doing wrong, you don't have to add constraints on button , for button `@api.multi` is ok , and if you use `@api.constraints` then no need to add `@api.multi`

Comment: But just with api.multi, how do I call those fields? I mean, these fields are from a One2many relationship, there's no other way to "call" them, isn't it?

Comment: Maybe 'depends', but I'm not sure, since these are lines, like on sale.order or purchase.order objects

Comment: @NeoVe I think you need to read odoo documentation first. Just go through it will give you more idea https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html

Comment: In this case i think, retrive `@api.constraint`, and replace it with `@api.one`

Comment: @Anonymousmiliana also here `if self.order_lines:` is not required , because you have used `for loop` inside it. so if no records found it will break from there. and `if not line.isbn:` , must be at the top.